# Implement cluster-based permutation test for regression

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme, permutation-test

I have worked with permutation testing previously to assess significance in classification problems. What you commonly do here is to randomly swap group labels to generate a null distribution. However, I am now working on a linear mixed model with a continuous outcome variable. I would like to know whether anyone sees a problem with using a similar approach here? To be more precise: I have a continuous outcome variable y that I have measured repeatedly at 1000 timepoints. I know want to analyze whether two factors (reward probability and magnitude as well as a random intercept per participant) relate to y over time and correct for significant clusters with a cluster-based permutation test. Is it also reasonable her to randomly mix the outcome variable y to generate a null distribution and to then compare the maximal F values for the main effects with that random permutation to assess significance?

Every help/discussion would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the only random effect you are fitting is the participant effect. And to fit your model i guess your data is in this format:

```
participant time [..other factors] y
1            1                     y11
1            2                     y12
....
2            1                     y21
```

Even if you use a cluster based permutation, that is a permutation within participant, you lose the relationship between the time variable and your response variable. And most likely your F-statistic will be quite low since the regression doesn't make sense at all.

Not very sure how your data is structured or what is the study design, the idea is to keep other factors unchanged and only test the variable you are interested in. So for example, if you want to test reward probability, then you need to reassign this to each individual randomly, run the regression again and see the F distribution.